# Write and read to/from cmd prompt with Python program

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, prompt

What have I to do in order to make a Python program write in the prompt something like "ls" and read (save in a .txt file) the output of the command?

Comment: I'm using linux and Python 3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can call a command with the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess

# Call the command with the subprocess module
# Be sure to change the path to the path you want to list
proc = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "/your/path/here"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Read stdout from the process
result = proc.stdout.read().decode()

# Be safe and close the stdout.
proc.stdout.close()

# Write the results to a file.
with open("newfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Do note though.. If you just want to list a directory, the `os` module has a `listdir()` method:

```
import os

with open("newfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in os.listdir("/your/path/here"):
        f.write(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python can be used to execute bash and batch commands (Linux & Windows), by making use of:

subprocess.check_call(["ls", "-l"])